# Laravel Eloquent Fill Model with multiple items

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I've created a step by step form that's filling a model with data, saving to a session and moving to the next step. Finally, at the final step, it will save all the data.

What I'm having issues with is I have a table that will need multiple entries. Something like:

```
$myValues=[
['user_id' => 3, 'genre_category_id'=> 5],
['user_id' => 7, 'genre_category_id'=> 2]
]
```

But doing this leads to an empty model when I try to print it out:

`$myModel->fill($myValues);`

Is there a way to fill with multiple items, or is there another efficient way to pass over this data to the final step where I can save it?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no way with models. You can do `DB::table('table')->insert($myValues);` if you don't need to use models.

Comment: Thank you! I was following along with a session idea of doing a step by step form but it seems it makes a lot more sense to have a database table that holds the last step the user was on and grab from there instead. Now I'm writing to the database on every step instead.

Comment: You can add your comment as the answer and I'll vote for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with models.

You can do `DB::table('table')->insert($myValues);` if you don't need to use models.